# Cant search or order sage transactions when data files are stored on VM Server

Tags: vmware-workstation

We are having an issue where Sage wont search or order the transaction screen of any company when the Company file in sage data is pointed to a VMware workstation hosted server.

All our client PC's can access the data stored on the VM, and sage pulls the company data through fine, but as soon as you try to search through thew transaction screen, it just flashes and doesn't do anything. When you point the company file back to the non-VM server, it then goes back to working fine.

Sage support haven't been able to help me at all with this. 
Has anyone had this issue before, and worked out what the cause of it is? I can only presume its to do with the configuration of the VM Server.

Here is some info on the VM:

```
Network = Bridged
Memory = 4 GB
OS = Windows Server Datacenter R2
Number of processors = 1
Hard Disk = 60 GB
```

Help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue Lied with permissions to the users on the domain, they need to specifically set to have full control over the sage data folders. This sorted the issue for me.